# PHP - apply discount to items divisible by 2

Tags: php, modulus

I am working with some code which will apply a discount to an item should the item be bought in multiples that are dividable by 2, this works if I put in any number dividable by 2.

The problem is if the user inputs say 3, I would still like the discount to be applied as they have bought 2 together plus another.

What would be the best approach to tackling this? This is the code I'm working with:

```
if($price == 11.99 && $each_item['quantity'] % 2 == 0)
{   
    $toAdd = 3.98 * ($each_item['quantity'] / 2);

    $discount += $toAdd; 

    $priceTotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];

    $priceTotal -= $discount;

    $finalDiscount += $discount;
}
```

Comment: Subtract 1 from quantity, do your calculation, then add `$price`.

Comment: Divide by 2, round down to an integer, that's the number of discounts to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the quantity by 2, and round it down to an integer to get the number of discounts to apply.

```
if ($price == 11.99) {
    $to_add = 3.98 * floor($each_item['quanity']/2);
    $discount += $toAdd;
    $priceTotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
    $priceTotal -= $discount;
    $finalDiscount += $discount;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, simple and easy to understand